# Grouping fields from one to many relationship in postgres

Tags: postgresql, aggregate, aggregate-functions

I need to group fields in a child table in one query in postgres.

I have following data

```
Stores:

| id | name |
|----|------|
| 1  | abcd |

Features:

| id | store | name | other |
|----|-------|------|-------|
| 1  | 1     | door | metal |
| 2  | 1     | fork | green |
```

I've got to this query

```
SELECT
  stores.id,
  stores.name,
  concate_ws(',', features.id, features.name, features.other)
FROM stores
LEFT JOIN features
  ON(features.store=stores.id)
WHERE stores.id =1
GROUP BY stores.id, features.id;
```

This is best I've got so far but yields 2 tuples

```
1, abcd, (1,door,metal)
1, abcd, (2,fork,green)
```

I'd like to be able to get one row with the features '|' concatenated like so

```
1, abcd ,(1,door,metal|2,fork,green)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `string_agg()`:

```
SELECT stores.id,
       stores.name,
       string_agg(concate_ws(',', features.id, features.name, features.other), '|') 
FROM stores
LEFT JOIN features ON features.store=stores.id
WHERE stores.id =1
GROUP BY stores.id, stores.name;
```